# How to make linear transfer function in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, function, transfer, simulink

Basicly I need to make k*(T*s+1) transfer function block in Simulink.
In Matlab it's easy as can be, I just make denominator lower then numerator and everything is fine. But when I'm trying to make the same thing with Simulink's block it gives me an error. [denomenator shouldnt be lower then numerator.
So what do you think?

Comment: Actually I tried parallel connection of derivative and gain already, and I tried PID without I part. But all of this things, when I'm trying to check this at matlab, giving me different bode plots. And it's not the same as 
s = tf('s');
H = k*(T*s+1);
so it's not right.

Comment: Or, what do I need to do to make transfer function with numerator lower then denominator in Simulink?

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing is contains a pure derivative component (`kTs`).  Numerical solvers cannot work with these components, and nature cannot realize them.  Intuitively, a pure derivative block in Simulink would have an unreasonably large response to numerical errors at very small timesteps.  If you are comfortable with Bode plots, a derivative component has arbitrarily large response at high frequencies

When using a derivative component you typically pick a break frequency in the response curve.  This is equivalent to applying a low pass filter to the inputs prior to the derivative operation.  If the low pass filter frequency is sufficiently faster than the system dynamics, then you get derivative behavior at the frequencies that you are interested in, while still having a realizable system.

So, to handle this in Simulink, you can either modify the transfer function yourself, or use one of the Simulink blocks which is derivative-aware, for example the "derivative" block or the "PID controller" block.  (Simulink should then work behind the scenes to make this work.)

For example, rewrite your equation as:

```
kTs + k
```

And use four blocks, like this:

```
---+---GAIN=kT----DERIVATIVE----SUM--
   |                             |
   +---GAIN=K--------------------+
```